# How to open a file using Excel VBA and turn off updating links

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a macro where I open up another file, copy data, and paste the data in my file with macro. The feeder file where I copy the data has links to other other workbooks. How would I have the macro continue without prompting me to update links.

```
Sub FeedFiles()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "T:\Planning\FY Budget\2018 Budget\Director Templates\With updates\2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - Thomson_V2.xlsx" _
, Password:="Thomson18"
Workbooks("2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP -Thomson_V2.xlsx").Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:AH227").Activate
Workbooks("2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - Thomson_V2.xlsx").Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:AH227").Copy
Workbooks("2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - Total 802.xlsm").Worksheets("Thomson").Range("A1:AH227").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Workbooks("2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - Thomson_V2.xlsx").Close

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In A Short:
[Workbooks.Open method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel) has several parameters. One of them is `UpdateLinks` which you have to set to `false`.

```
Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="FullePathToExcelFile", UpdateLinks:=False)
```

Try! Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Use `False` to disable updating links; e.g.,

```
Workbooks.Open(xxx.xlsx, False)
```

I was further getting a Type Mismatch (Run-time Error 13). In order to suppress the error window, use `On Error Resume Next` before the `Workbook.open` command.

The below steps should work seamlessly to avoid this issue.

```vb
On Error Resume Next
Set EIB = Workbooks.Open(xxxx, False)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```